# Make a very simple android application to exchange two-digit numbers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, node.js

I want to make a small android app (using phonegap and web languages) that :
1. connects random people from the internet who are, at any time, using that system.
2. exchange simple one or two digit numbers.

example: you turn on that "application" and you see a text box (this basic thing must be made in html) where you type a number and any other randomly connected user of the application can see it in a text box and vice versa.

What resources/languages will i need?

Thank you!

Comment: from where you will get people data ??

Comment: That's what i want to know. i have no people data. i just want to randomly connect any two people

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you must use PhoneGap but you could reasonably just download the Android SDK which uses the Eclipse IDE. Then with some simple XML you could quite easily create the layout for your application, the various pages (activities as they are known on Android) of your application and link it all using Android based Java.

For the connection, you need to decide whether your going to be using a client to client connection (so two android phones directly network each other) or a client-server model.

Personally I prefer the client-server model if you're sending tiny pieces of data using TCP. Anything much, for example, game data, video data etc would probably require UDP, which is much faster but a lot more unreliable (which is what skype uses). TCP doesn't allow data loss, well, it does but guarantees all your data will be delivered as you sent it and UDP is used when your allowed to lose some data packets (e.g. a video feed may look blurry because data packets are being lost via UDP).

Client - Client has a lot of implications and I would recommend you focus on the following in summary:

- XML (you can pick this up as you develop Android apps)
- Java (not hard to pick up if you're already into basic programming etc)
- Establishing TCP server connections in Java.
- Program a Java based server (or other language) to handle and process each clients request.

Good Luck!